# javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

i have Html document A.html and javascript file A.js, how to write a code in javascript within html body THAT SPECIFIES FUNCTION res AS THE EVENT HANDLER FOR THE onclick EVENT FOR THE BUTTON DEFINED IN THE FORM?

A.html-----------

```
<body>
<form>
<input type = "button" id="butt1" value = "Press for Results" /><br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't decipher what you're trying to achieve.. Do you have a button in a.html and want it to call a function defined in a.js when it's clicked?

Comment: i believe he wants a function called `res` that acts like `onclick` action for a button.

Comment: and @sira, you don't have to shout.

Comment: @ Marty yes i want the same as u told but the code will be within Html javascript

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty poorly written question, but I think what you want to do is pretty straightforward.  When you include an external script with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
```

It's all there for the following execution. Thus if A.js has the following:

```
function res() {
   ...
}
```

You can use specify that in your HTML, as such:

```
<button onclick="res()" value="call res()">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean..

**a.html**:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input onclick="javascript:res();" type="button" id="butt1" value="Press for Results" /><br />
    </form>
</body>
```

**a.js**:

```
function res()
{
    alert("function logic to go here");
}
```

If you want all the code on the one page..

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function res()
        {
            alert("function logic to go here");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input onclick="javascript:res();" type="button" id="butt1" value="Press for Results" /><br />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="A.js">
 <form>
   <input type="button" name="test" value="Click me" onclick="inform()">
 </form>
```

A.js

```
function inform(){
    alert("You have activated me by clicking the grey button! Note that the event handler is added within the event that it handles, in this case, the form button event tag")
    }
```

All at once

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function inform(){
alert("You have activated me by clicking the grey button! Note that the event handler is added within the event that it handles, in this case, the form button event tag")
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" id="button" name="test" value="Click me" onclick="inform()">
</form>
```

Calling function in javascript

```
if(condition in which you want onclick to b called)
   document.getElementById('button').click();
```

Comment: but i need onclick event for the button outside form means in javascript

Comment: @Sira if you need onclick event for the button outside then why you don't use jquery? It will be easy for you i think.

Comment: @Nick u wrote onclick event for button with in form but i need it outside form ..........means within javascript of A.html that will call res () of A.js

Comment: @Sira use jquery bind event to your button . easy ... eh

Comment: @sira I just edited the answer Hope that helps.... this may give some problem in mozilla

Comment: @sira 


Calling function in javascript

if(condition in which you want onclick to b called)
   document.getElementById('button').click();